# Login Troube with Prestashop Adminwindow

Tags: prestashop-1.7

When I try to log-in into the prestashop admin area,

This **error** appears:

[image]

Does someone know why this error is coming? It came suddenly, there were no changes made.

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when connection to prestashop.com does not work correctly.
Simply delete all `.xml` files in your folder `config\xml`.